# Unable to set ymin/ymax properly in matplotlib axvspan

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a political compass style scatter plot, and I'd like each of the 4 quadrants to have a different background color:

[image]

Trying to do this with `axvspan`. Here's me trying to do the lower-left quadrant:

```
ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
plt.axvspan(xmin,0,ymin,0,facecolor='g', alpha=0.5)
```

Nothing happens, the plot is still completely white. However if I set the `ymin` and `ymax` to positive values, it sort of works - it's just fills the entire y axis, ignoring the specific ymin/ymax values I set.

```
ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
plt.axvspan(xmin,0,0,1,facecolor='g', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

So to summarize, `axvspan` doesn't like a negative range for the y values and won't show anything. And if I set the y values to a positive range, those particular values are ignored and instead the entire y axis is filled. `axhspan` works similarly with the x value range. Why is it like this? Is there an alternative I can use for coloring the 4 quadrants?

Comment: Check the description of the `ymin` and `ymax` parameters in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html)... they're in y-axis units (0-1), not data units.

Comment: Seems like an odd design choice for ymin/ymax to be in different units than xmin/xmax, but ok...